# ROS Answers SE migration: p2os problem!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
I'm using kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04 and my robot is Pioneer p3at and I'm trying to make it autonomous!
but I have a problem ,
when I run the package I faced this Error:

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [p2os_urdf/publisher]: can't locate node [publisher] in package [p2os_urdf]

every helpful hints will be appreciated.
p.s: I installed the p2os_urdf package but nothing change!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257589/p2os-problem!!/) by [saba.k](https://answers.ros.org/users/29739/saba.k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

The node type that you request in the launch file does not exist.
According to the CMakeList of the p2os_urdf package (https://github.com/allenh1/p2os/blob/master/p2os_urdf/CMakeLists.txt) the node type is  "p2os_publisher".

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saba.k](https://answers.ros.org/users/29739/saba.k/) on 2017-04-04**:
thank you for your help:)

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-03-26**:
If anyone is here from https://wiki.ros.org/p2os-purdue/Tutorials/P2OS%20Stage%20Simulation on Indigo, update `p2os/p2os_urdf/launch/pioneer3dx_urdf.launch` to `type="p2os_publisher"`